# Hide String if Child is empty after filtering v-for list in VueJS

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuetify.js

I'm stuck trying to hide a title in vuejs.
I have a v-for which goes trough Months and it give me 12 div
in this v-for, i have another v-for with my data which have date for each item

and with a v-if, i match the month of the item with the month of my first v-for and display it.

But i add filter on it and it's possible for example that April has no data after filtering.

So i tried to hide the name of the month (date.nom in my code) which is in the first, if the second loop is empty but with the v-if, the div outside the 2nd loop is not really empty.

I tried to fin a qway to add it in my second v-for but it displays, logically, the name on top of each item.
maybe there is a way to display it for the first item only ?

```
          <v-row v-for="(date,index) in dates" :key="date.id">
            <v-col cols="12" v-if="monthDate >= date.nombre">
              <span>{{date.nom}}</span>
            </v-col>
            <div v-for="(histo, index) in orderBy(itemsFiltered, 'date_publication', -1)" :key="index"">
              <div v-if="getYearDate(histo.date_publication) == year">
                <div v-if="getMonthDate(histo.date_publication) == date.nombre && monthDate >= date.nombre">

                  <v-col cols="12">
                    <div>
                      <div class="parent-img-histofull">

                        <img :src="histo.cover_medium" lazy class="img-album-histofull" />

                        <span >{{getDayDate(histo.date_publication)}}</span>

                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </v-col>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </v-row>
```

Comment: You mean you need to hide the inner `v-for`div if `itemsFiltered` array is empty?

Comment: i need to hide the span <span>{{date.nom}}</span> if the the inner v-for is empty
but of course not for all months, April may be empty but not March

Comment: maybe instead of a v-for in `dates` which hold all of your data, you should return a computed variable which has your already filtered data.

Comment: You mean create only one v-for with a computed propery and put itemFiltered inside ?

Comment: I still don't get it, i did'nt succeed yet